# Singular Values of Matrix as Optimization Problem

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-optimization, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-optimization

Assume that $A$ is a positive semidefinite symmetric matrix.

It is known that $$\max_{||y||\leq1} \quad y^TAy$$

Has an analytical solution which is the maximum eigenvalue of $A$.

This isn't hard to derive either. We can do so by writing it as a constrained minimization problem and solving using KKT. 
\begin{align}
\min_{||y||\leq1} &\quad -y^TAy\\
L(y,\lambda)&=-y^TAy-\lambda(1-y^Ty)\\
\nabla_yL(y,\lambda)&=-Ay+\lambda y\\
\mbox{Setting }\nabla_yL(y,\lambda)&=0\\
Ay&=\lambda y
\end{align}
It is easy to see that the $y$ which satisfy the KKT conditions are the eigenvectors of $A$ and the highest eigenvalue gives the best objective function value.

---

My question is, if now, $A$ is a rectangular matrix, is the largest singular value of $A$, the solution to the problem $$\max_{\|x\|\leq1,\|y\|\leq1} \quad x^TAy$$
where $A\in \Re^{m\times n}, x\in \Re^{m\times 1}, y\in \Re^{n\times 1}$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that's true. It follows easily from two simple facts:

**1) For $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$, $x^TAy$ is bounded from above by the maximal singular value of $A$.**

If $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$, then $x^TAy\leq\|x\|\|Ay\|\leq\|x\|\|A\|\|y\|=\|A\|=\sigma_1$.

**2) $x^TAy=\sigma_1$ for some $x$ and $y$ such that $\|x\|=\|y\|=1$.**

Let $A=USV^T$ be the SVD with the singular values in the descending order on the diagonal of $S$ and let $e_1$ be the first column of the identity matrix of an appropriate dimension. Then taking $x=Ue_1$ and $y=Ve_1$ gives
$x^TAy=e_1^TU^TUSV^TVe_1=e_1^TSe_1=\sigma_1$.

Comment: Hi! Where did you get this 'fact'? I know it happens, but can you point me to a formal proof?

Answer (score 1):

The singular values of $A$ are the eigenvalues of the symmetric matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}0&A\\A^T&0\end{bmatrix}$$

Following your first insight, this would mean that the largest eigenvalue can be characterized by

$$\max_{\|x\|^2+\|y\|^2\le 1} 2x^TAy$$

The set of vectors $(x,y)$ with  $\|x\|\le 1$ and $\|y\|\le1$ is strictly larger than the unit ball of the combined dimensions, so that your second formula will give the wrong value.

---

Let's check what the torus variant comes up to. The Lagrangian is

$$L(x,y,λ,μ)=x^TAy+\fracλ2(1-x^Tx)+\fracμ2(1-y^Ty)$$

resulting in the KKT equations $Ay=μx$, $A^Tx=λy$, and the original norm conditions, so that

$$μ=μx^Tx=x^TAy=λy^Ty=λ\text{ and } AA^Tx=λμx=λ^2x\text{ or } A^TAy=λμy=λ^2y.$$

Thus also resulting in the correct singular value and singular vectors.

Comment: You are missing a two somewhere: $\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}^T\begin{bmatrix}0 & A \\ A^T & 0\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\end{bmatrix}=x^TAy+y^TA^Tx=2x^TAy$. Using the same approach as in my answer, you get that both maxima (with yours fixed by multiplying it by two) give the same value: the maximal singular value of $A$.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I was more concerned with the correct singular vectors. Are you sure that the different geometric shape of the domain does not result in different locations of the maxima?

Comment: I'm not sure but it seems to me that the maximums are attained at same $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Yes, see the other answer and my addendum. Both formulations have the same solutions, only different scalings.